# Automatically Specifying Where on the Page Chapter Endnotes Begin

Tags: luatex, lists, titles, endnotes, raise

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote\endnote
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % Needed to restart endnote numbering at 1 with each new chapter.     
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newlength{\skipnote}
\setlength{\skipnote}{1.5ex} 


\let\latexchapter\chapter
\makeatletter  %changes the catcode of @ to 11
\renewcommand\enoteheading{
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
    \latexchapter*{\notesname\markboth{NOTES}{}}
    \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip
    \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
}

\def\@endanenote{\par\vskip\skipnote\endgroup}%

\def\enotedivision#1#2{\@ifnextchar\enotedivision{}{#1{#2}}}
\pretocmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\setcounter{endnote}{0}}{}{} % reset counter
\makeatother    

\begin{document}
\LARGE
    
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents.}
\tableofcontents
    
    \chapter*{Chapter I}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter I.}}
    Some words.\footnote{\lipsum[13]} Some words.\footnote{\lipsum[57]} Some words.\footnote{Another endnote.}
    
    \renewcommand{\notesname}{Chapter I. Endnotes} 
    \addtoendnotes{\unexpanded{\enotedivision{}{}}}
    \theendnotes
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter I. Endnotes.}}
\end{document}
```

which produces the Endnotes list:

[image]

QUESTION: How may I specify where on the page I would like the title and subsequent endnotes to begin? In this case, I would like to raise them so as to accommodate a greater number of endnotes on the initial page. I know I can use a `\vspace*` after `\notesname{` but I thought, perhaps, there might be amore automatic way of accomplishing this, say, for all the chapter endnotes in a document.

I compile the code with `lualatex`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `book` class `\chapter*`

As that forces a page break you can't simply add a space before the heading as you could for a section, but you can locally redefine the command that sets started chapter heads thedefault is

```
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

so change that `50\p@` (which you could write as 50pt) to whatever you want.

Comment: Many thanks for this very helpful and informative answer.